# Url req node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

Hi i have a simple problem with req.params in `Node.js` and `AngularJS`:

I'm trying to find user by username in `Mongoose` by sending the username from Get req.

Here is the code:

```
router.get('/profileByUsername/:username', function(req, res){
        let username = req.params.username;
        Profile.findOne({username: username}, function(err, profile){
            if(err) res.json({success: false, message: 'אין מידע קיים'});
            if(profile) res.json({success: false, message: 'הצליח', info: profile});
        })
    });
```

This is the factory:

```
mainFactory.getUserByUsername = function(username) {
            console.log(username);
            return $http.get('/pr/profileByUsername/' +username);
        }
```

This is the admin (Adm is the mainFactory):

```
this.getUserByUsername = function(){
            let username = $routeParams.username;
            Mcs.getUserByUsername(username).then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
        }
```

The problem is the req send 10000 times
[image]

Comment: How do you call your getUserbyusername function?

Comment: Mcs.getUserByUsername

Comment: I mean your controller function, not factory

Comment: I use route and call it ControllerAs: pnaelAdmin